# "const" in C and Error "assignment of read-only location"

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a linking list in C, here is my code

```
struct strlist {
    char * const data;
    struct strlist *next;
}
```

I add `const` behind `data` to avoid anyone modify data pointer like this:

```
struct strlist S = { "Hello World" };
printf("%s", S.data++);
printf("%s", S.data)
```

then I use this function to add new element

```
int Append(struct strlist *S, char *a) {
    struct strlist next = { a };
    S->next = malloc(sizeof(struct strlist));
    *S->next = next;
    return 0; 
}
```

In Clang It can be compile, and work.
but in gcc I get the Error `assignment of read-only location`
Why? Is there better method?

`char * const str` It means I can change the string but not pointer, isn't it?

why I can't copy struct to the `next`?

Comment: Copying will surely also change the pointer.

Comment: Which line is giving the error? `*S->next = next;` ?

Comment: Yes,"error: assignment of read-only location '*S->next'
    *S->next = next;"

Comment: You are indeed storing a new value into read only location `S->next->data` by assigning the whole structure with `*S->next = next;`  **gcc**: 1, **clang**: 0.  You could file a bug report with the clang team.